# Skewness and correlation

Tags: correlation, data-transformation, skewness

I have a data set on which I want to run a machine learning algorithm. Some of the columns are skewed.

If I apply a transformation (let's say log) to those columns and I want to display the matrix of correlations, should I do it before or after transforming the skewed columns, or should I not do it all?

Does it become meaningless after this transformation?

(original:)

> J'ai un jeu de données avec des colonnes "skewed" sur lequel j'applique de l'apprentissage automatique , après une transformation log sur ces colonnes , si je veux la matrice de corrélation dois-je la faire avant ou après la transformation ou ne pas le faire du tout ? perd-elle tout sens après cette transformation?

Comment: From the network FAQ: [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: @william3031 Thanks, however, this is the older post; normally the repost should close in favor of this one.

Answer (score 1):

It would be worth displaying the matrix both before and after the transformation.
Correlation is a measure of strength of the linear relationship between two variables.
Lets say If after the log transformation the correlation is higher in magnitude than before, it tells you that there is a stronger relationship between log(x) and y than just x and y