# Correlation and skewness

Tags: variance, skewness

I have a data set on which i want to run a machine learning algorithm , some of the columns are skewed. If I apply a transformation (lets say log) to those columns and I want to display the matrix of correlation , should i do it before or after handling skewed columns or should i not do it all ?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Skewness and correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/431646/skewness-and-correlation). Please edit your questions rather than reposting them.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We need more information to be able to answer this. What machine language algorithm do you want to apply? Why do you want that? What are your variables? What is your goal?